# How to get user roles from auth0 in fastapi?

Tags: authorization, fastapi, auth0, user-roles, pyjwt

I use **FastAPI** and **Auth0** to restrict access to specific endpoints for specific users. In the Auth0 dashboard, I have defined various user roles and assigned them to individual users. As a result, each user possesses a role.

Currently, my objective is to retrieve the user's roles. I added this code to `Auth pipline > Rules` to get user roles in token:

```js
    function (user, context, callback) {
      var namespace = 'https://domain.auth0.com/';
      context.idToken[namespace] = user.roles;
      return callback(null, user, context);
    }
```

This is my FastAPI code that should retrieve the user token. (I am not sure whether to get user roles here or not).

```py
    from dataclasses import dataclass
    
    import jwt
    from config import settings
    from custom_exceptions import BadCredentialsException, UnableCredentialsException
    
    
    @dataclass
    class JsonWebToken:
        """Perform JSON Web Token (JWT) validation using PyJWT"""
    
        jwt_access_token: str
        auth0_issuer_url: str = f"https://{settings.auth0_domain}/"
        auth0_audience: str = settings.auth0_audience
        algorithm: str = "RS256"
        jwks_uri: str = f"{auth0_issuer_url}.well-known/jwks.json"
    
        def validate(self):
            try:
                jwks_client = jwt.PyJWKClient(self.jwks_uri)
                jwt_signing_key = jwks_client.get_signing_key_from_jwt(
                    self.jwt_access_token
                ).key
                payload = jwt.decode(
                    self.jwt_access_token,
                    jwt_signing_key,
                    algorithms=self.algorithm,
                    audience=self.auth0_audience,
                    issuer=self.auth0_issuer_url,
                )
            except jwt.exceptions.PyJWKClientError:
                raise UnableCredentialsException
            except jwt.exceptions.InvalidTokenError:
                raise BadCredentialsException
            return payload



When I print `payload`: 

    {
        'iss': 'https://domain.auth0.com/', 
        'sub': 'kjn8DLZ6TNJ!9ube$rvE@clients', 
        'aud': 'https://domain.auth0.com/api/v2/', 
        'iat': 1694021374, 
        'exp': 1696613374, 
        'azp': 'kjn8DLZ6TNJ!9ube$rvE', 
        'gty': 'client-credentials'
    }
```